# Cambiar colores a un grafico con plot, ggtern o ggplot?

Tags: r

Este es mi script.
Basicamente es para calcular la diversidad beta de una comunidad como recambio de especie, riqueza o limitantes como factores esterantes. es necesario instalar una librería para poder tener los mismos efectos personalizados?. Abajo le dejo mi scrip y mi pregunta

```
library (adespatial)
library (ade4)
library (betapart)
if (require(ade4, quietly = TRUE))
data(habitat)
habitat.pod.J <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "J", quant = FALSE)
# Sorensen
habitat.pod.S <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "S", quant = FALSE)
# Ruzicka
habitat.pod.qJ <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "J", quant = TRUE)
# Percentage difference
habitat.pod.qS <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "S", quant = TRUE)
# Data frames for the triangular plots
# Data frames for the triangular plots
habitat.pod.J.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.J$D),
habitat.pod.J$repl,
habitat.pod.J$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.J.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "RichDiff")
habitat.pod.S.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.S$D),
habitat.pod.S$repl,
habitat.pod.S$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.S.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "RichDiff")
habitat.pod.qJ.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.qJ$D),
habitat.pod.qJ$repl,
habitat.pod.qJ$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.qJ.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "AbDiff")
habitat.pod.qS.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.qS$D),
habitat.pod.qS$repl,
habitat.pod.qS$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.qS.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "AbDiff")
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.J.3[, c(3, 1, 2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "RichDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "Jaccard similarity", cex = 1.5)
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.S.3[, c(3 ,1 ,2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "RichDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "Sorensen similarity", cex = 1.5)
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.qJ.3[, c(3, 1, 2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "AbDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "S = 1 – Ružička D", cex = 1.5)
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.qS.3[, c(3, 1, 2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "AbDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "S = 1 – Percentage difference", cex = 1.5)
# Display values of the mean points in the triangular plots
colMeans(habitat.pod.J.3[, c(3, 1, 2)])
colMeans(habitat.pod.S.3[, c(3, 1, 2)])
colMeans(habitat.pod.qJ.3[, c(3, 1, 2)])
```

Necesito ke la linea que sale por dentro del triangulo sea de un color ejmplo rojo, y los puntos sean azul !!!

Comment: Has tratado de emplear [triangle.class](https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/ade4/ade4-html/triangle.class.html) asimismo quisiera testear el código, pero consigo `Warning in install.packages :
  package 'adehabitat' is not available (for R version 3.5.1)`  así que voy a efectuar una consulta sobre este particular en otro [trend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235926/c%C3%B3mo-conseguir-el-package-xxx-si-no-est%C3%A1-disponible-para-la-versi%C3%B3n-r-w-y-z).

Comment: No nunca he usado triabgle.class no se como usarlo!!

Comment: el paquete adespatial esta disponible puedes correr el codigo en https://rstudio.cloud