# Cómo conseguir el package "XXX" si no está disponible para la versión R w.y.z

Tags: r, packages

Estuve interesado en probar este [script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235863/cambiar-colores-a-un-grafico-con-plot-ggtern-o-ggplot)

Para ello necesitaba `install.packages("adehabitat")` pero obtuve:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'adehabitat' is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

Traté con

```
install.packages('adehabitat',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

Y siguió apareciendo el mensaje de alerta antes señalado.

Tengo entendido de acuerdo a este [post](https://www.haktansuren.com/installing-r-package-from-the-source/) que es necesario verificar si el citado package, se encuentra disponible en la página web de [can-r](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html), pero al revisar no figura en dicho enlace.

En todo caso cómo tener la certeza de que el package "XXX", existe o ha existido... se podría hacer un script con [library("XML")](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) para verificar si alguno de los [mirro-r](https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/) lo puede contener.

Cualquier sugerencia gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el caso particular de `adehabitat` el paquete fue retirado de CRAN, el repositorio a través del cuál se distribuyen los paquetes de R. Según https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitat/ se retiró a pedido de quién lo mantenía. Los mirrors de CRAN, como su nombre lo indica, son copias tan actualizadas como es posible del repositorio principal de CRAN. Por lo tanto, si un paquete sale de CRAN sale también de los mirrors. Puede haber un breve desfase por el tiempo que estos demoran en actualizarse, pero tienen que salir.

## Solución

La alternativa que nos queda cuando pasan este tipo de cosas es recurrir al archivo de CRAN, que tiene versiones anteriores de paquetes, incluidos los que salieron de CRAN por un motivo u otro. Desde el archive se puede descargar el código del paquete en un tarball e instalarlo. En https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source hay instrucciones para hacerlo.

## Advertencia

Instalar un paquete (sobre todo un paquete "caído" y más aún si lleva mucho tiempo en ese estado) desde el source puede traer bastantes complicaciones. Cuando instalamos desde CRAN no solo instalamos el paquete, también sus dependencias. Habrás visto que muchas veces al instalar un paquete se instalan otros antes, esas son dependencias, paquetes que el paquete necesita para funcionar. Los paquetes en CRAN tienen una virtud: siempre tienen dependencias resueltas y libres de conflictos de versiones. Un paquete fuera de CRAN (por ejemplo, en el archivo de CRAN) no tiene esas garantías y quizás necesitemos resolver nosotros las dependencias, lo cuál es muy laborioso y puede además generar conflictos con nuestra instalación de R, al usar versiones pasadas de los paquetes requeridas por el paquete fuera de CRAN e incompatibles con los demás paquetes. Además puede ser que el paquete requiera compilación, por lo que nuestro sistema debería tener las herramientas de compilación necesarias.

## Sugerencias

Mi recomendación sería evitar en la medida de lo posible usar paquetes fuera CRAN, buscando reemplazos si los hay. Si es absolutamente necesario, la segunda mejor opción sería hacer una instalación paralela de R (en una máquina virtual, contenedor, etc.) para hacer andar el paquete problemático. De este modo no ponemos en riesgo nuestra versión de producción de R.

Otra buena idea es que esa máquina virtual corra Linux, lo que facilita mucho disponer de herramientas necesarias de compilación si son necesarias. No es que no se pueda con otros sistemas, es que las instalaciones de Linux normalmente traen compiladores para casi todo o hacen muy fácil instarlas. Claro, si no estamos familiarizados puede tener sus problemas también.

Con respecto a tu última pregunta (como saber si un paquete existe o existió), a mí lo que mejor me funciona es una búsqueda con el nombre del paquete en google o duckduckgo. Seguramente se podrías hacer un script que recorra CRAN y/o el archivo de CRAN, pero no le veo mucho sentido a automatizar un proceso que muy probablemente cause problemas o requiera bastante intervención del usuario/a para funcionar.

Comment: Excelente aporte @mpaladino, hay muchas cosas rescatables al momento de instalar `package` que no figuran en [r-can](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html), no obstante mi inquietud inicial me llevó a buscar `packages` fuera de `r-can` específicamente en github [Installing R Packages from GitHub](https://www.displayr.com/installing-r-packages-from-github/) porque estaba interesado en aprender cómo crear gráficos parecidos a la [BBC news](https://github.com/bbc/bbplot) De todas formas siempre es bueno cruzar información y compartirla con la comunidad.